# grails - findBy highest id AND another criteria

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, findby

I've looked a bunch of answers to this question here on SO and elsewhere but all I can track down is cases where people just want to find the highest id, the max dateCreated or the latest db entry but what I want to do is retrieve the latest object created that also matches another criteria. My domain class has the following properties: `id`, `number`, `company`, `type`, `dateCreated` and `content`. The `company` property can only be set to 'OYG' or 'BAW' and the `number` property is an auto incrementing int. What I want to do is retrieve the record with the highest `number` that also has its `company` property set to 'OYG' or 'BAW`.

So here's an example:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id |  number | company |   type  | dateCreated | content |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |    0    |   OYG   | TsAndCs |  15/09/2016 |  stuff  |
|  2 |    0    |   BAW   | TsAndCs |  15/09/2016 |  stuff  |  
|  3 |    1    |   OYG   | TsAndCs |  16/09/2016 |  stuff  | 
|  4 |    2    |   OYG   | TsAndCs |  17/09/2016 |  stuff  | 
|  5 |    1    |   BAW   | TsAndCs |  16/09/2016 |  stuff  | 
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to say def doc = Document.findBy**Highest**NumberAndCompany('OYG') then it should bring back the object with id 4. def doc = Document.findBy**Highest**NumberAndCompany('BAW') should bring back id 5's object, etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite Joshua Moore gave you a good solution, there is another simplier in one line.

```
MyDomain.findAllByCompany(company, [sort: 'number', order: 'desc', limit: 1])?.first()
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be easy enough if you order by the number in descending order, and limit your results to one. So perhaps something like this?

```
String companyName = 'OYG'
def results = MyDomain.createCriteria().list() {
    eq("company", companyName)
    maxResults(1)
    order("number", "desc")
}
println results[0].id // will print 4
```

Using this approach you could create a named query so you can pass the company name as a parameter.